# Words in one column merging with the second column in latex

Tags: two-column

[image]When I am writing an article in two columns, at some places the last word of the first column is merging with the second column.

I am using these commands

```
\documentclass[journal=jpcld,manuscript=letter,twocolumns]{achemso}
\twocolumn
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please extend your code fragment to complete small document (with dummy text) which reproduce your problem. if only  word "alzheimer's" spill out. try manually insert in it hyphenation marks: `Alz\-hei\-mer`

Comment: Hello and welcome, please give a fully compilable code.

Comment: The problem here is that "Alzheimer" is not automatically hyphenated by (La)TeX.  There are two approaches.  (1) If the word might appear more than once in the document, put this in the preamble: `\hyphenation{Alz-hei-mer}`; this is probably the best approach here.  (2) If this is the only instance of the word, or a very specific break is needed, insert a discretionary hyphen in situ: `Alz\-heimer` (this is also suggested in another comment).